# Email template - Outlook 2013 view in browser IE Document Mode 5

Tags: internet-explorer-11, emulation, outlook-2013, email-templates

I have an email template sent to and viewed on outlook 2013.. viewing it on the browser (all ok at this point).. i click on view in browser.. it launches Internet explorer 11..the page breaks.. when I debug it shows document mode is set to 5 by default. When I change this to 7 it works perfectly.

I now copy all this html and make a local file, try with IE and it opens in edge mode (newer IE) no problems.. by default..

Anyone know what could be causing this original html to trigger document mode 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
<!-- Use Internet Explorer 9 Standards mode -->
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
```

It will make the content to render in IE9 and above compatible.

Need more info here is the link : [Specifying legacy document modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx)